# Secure connection between Oracle client and Oracle Server

Tags: communication, security, oracle11g

I wanted to do secure communication between Oracle client and Oracle server. 
Oracle version: 11g
Whether anyone know how to configure secure communication with Oracle server and client?
What are the configuration need to be done?

Thanks

Santhosh

Comment: By secure do you mean encrypted network traffic?

Comment: Yes.. During communication with server commands fired should not be whizible in cleartext.

Answer (score 1):

The following documents show how to do this 
[docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10746/asoconfg.htm#i1006517),
[example](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/11gr2_db_prod/security/network_encrypt/ntwrkencrypt.htm) with gui and how to steps to prove encryption

EDIT
I have never configured the thin client for this but the documentation for how to is [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10746/asojbdc.htm#ASOAG030)

Comment: Hi
Thank you very much for the answer..
Is there any way to do this using JDBC Connecter(Using Thin Client)?
It will be very helpfull If any one give this implementation!! Got stuck Doing this from a week!!